# Are there "points of no return" in KoA:R?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

Are there any decision points in *Kingdoms of Amalur: Reckoning* where:

- sidequests are locked (no longer available to complete)
- the main quest splits

...or any other points of no return? (Blocking an old location that is no longer required for a plot is fine.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there aren't any points of no return. You can even continue playing after finishing the main story.

There are a couple of branching questlines, but those should be obvious before making a decision.